# How to send the value of a variable from Node.js to the browser?

Tags: node.js

I don't understand why I can't get the value of "i" in the browser.
I got this Erreur 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET)

```
var http = require('http');
var i=0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    i++;
    res.writeHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.write(i);
    res.end();
}).listen(80, "127.0.0.1");
```

But it does work if :

```
res.write("i =" + i);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer:

Because the type of `i` is **number**.

Long Answer:

Take a look at [`Socket.prototype.write`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/net.js#L593) definition:

```
Socket.prototype.write = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
  if (typeof chunk !== 'string' && !Buffer.isBuffer(chunk))
    throw new TypeError('invalid data');
  return stream.Duplex.prototype.write.apply(this, arguments);
};
```